# Ajax reload DIV after form submit issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Ok so I have a script that layers data throughout the process (an online test, data is kept for up to 50 questions). I have recently found that my Ajax and jquery code is not stopping all users from getting a secondary page that is meant to be reloaded in place of a DIV currently on the page. All information is passed through the jquery and ajax and works great, but sometimes on a users very first visit and first question it loads the page that is just meant to replace the DIV information currently and is not meant to be visible.

**Here is my Ajax & jquery code:**

```
<script>
    $("#quizForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
        $.post( post_url, form_data, function( response ) {
        $("#prntqst").html( response );
        dataLayer.push({"event" : "formSubmitted", "formName" : "'.$this->quizID.'"});
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div id="prntqst"> <!-- this is DIV set to be reloaded -->
<font class="prntqst-text">Question Goes Here</font>
<form id="quizForm" action="ajax.php" method="post"> <!-- Script setup to handle submitted data -->
<input type="hidden" id="next_question" name="next_question" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="quiz_type" name="quiz_type" value="learning">
<input type="hidden" id="quiz_name" name="quiz_name" value="knowledge-1">
<label class="container" for="a">Ans A
<input type="radio" name="answers[1]" id="a" value="a">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" for="b">Ans B
<input type="radio" name="answers[1]" id="b" value="b">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" for="c">Ans C
<input type="radio" name="answers[1]" id="c" value="c">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<div class="subbtn_contain">
<div class="submitbtn">
<input id="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Next Question">
</div>
</div></div>
</form>
<!-- currently this is the location of Ajax and jquery script -->
<div>
```

So when the form is submitted it processes the data through the ajax.php page, and then page reloads the next question into the "prntqst" DIV, after the first page load every request is sent to the ajax.php location, and all subsequent reloads carry all of the data needed for the test to work properly. However I find that if I use a new computer, or clear the cache the very first request can sometimes result in the user be pushed to the location of the ajax.php instead of them staying at the current URL with a DIV reload.

I have verified this issue through my analytics account, 99% of the time a user still shows at the correct URL as if the ajax is properly reloading the DIV, however sometimes it does show a user directly at the ajax.php script.

Any ideas or comments would be appreciated,

Thanks again!

Comment: You should have at least an error in console due to `processData: false;`. Something like `processData is undefined` of a parse error like `unexpected ":"`...  -- I'm surprised it works 99% of the time.

Comment: I works with or without that line, so I will be removing it. After playing around some, if the page gets close to or loads all the way the issue doesn't occur. If when the page first loads the submit button is pushed it loads the ajax.php script in the bowers bar. So it seems like more of a loading issue.

Comment: I tried adding the code to the header of the page, but it doesn't work at all when that is done. Could it be that the code just needs moved up further in the code? Possibly before the submit button?

Comment: By push to the location of "ajax.php" you mean the user gets redirected to that specific PHP page, right?

Comment: And one other thing, the Html you provided, is it accurate? because the closing form tag seems to be out of the "prntqst" div. As you are overwriting HTML in the "prntqst" div this might cause issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see now.

If you can have "some garbage" inside a code block and, as you say

> works with or without that line...

That's because that code block is not even running at all.

The `processData: false` is a value assignation to an object property. It is ouside any object, in the code you provided. Then it seems like you tried to comment it like this: `<!-- removed from code processData: false; -->`, which also should throw an error. That is the HTML way to comment lines. in JS, it would be `// removed from code processData: false;`.

So... It seems that the form submits anyway. That just can the the "normal" form submit where the whole page reloads. **As a test**. Please try your page with that script completely removed. You should see no difference.

---

There is something else to explain here. You are playing with "dynamic" elements. Those are elements that didn't exist on page load and were added after... Or element that were there and were removed/replaced.

You have to write the script in such that this situation is handled.

In `$("#quizForm").submit(function(event){` an event handler is attached to the element `#quizForm`. If there is no such element in the page when the page first load... Or there is a parsing error... The function won't run. So the `event.preventDefault()` won't be called either.

Then, assuming you fixed all errors in that code block and it runs. It squarely replaces all the HTML inside `#prntqst`. So for the second submit, the element on which the event handler was attached is not there anymore and the function won't run again.

---

**The solution** for that is to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach the event handler to the `document` and "delegate" it to the `#quizForm` (if exist when the handler is called).

That is `$(document).on("event", "delegated_element_selector", function(){`

So when the "event" fires within the "document", a lookup is made to find the  "delegated_element_selector" and if found, the handler is executed.

That way is the way to have some event handler for the dynamic elements in a page.

Additionnally, about your question where to place the code, I added a `$(document).ready()` handler, which ensures the initial page load is complete before trying any jQuery lookup on some elements. So you can place that script where you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("submit", "#quizForm", function (event) {

    console.log("Custom submit")

    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
    $.post(post_url, form_data, function (response) {

      console.log(response)
      $("#prntqst").html(response);
      dataLayer.push({ event: "formSubmitted", formName: "'.$this->quizID.'" });
    });
  });
});
```

Now you should see *"Custom submit"* in the console on each form submit. And you should see what is the response too.

About `post_url` , I didn't any `action` attribute to the `<form>`... Maybe you just did not post it here on SO. Make sure there is one. Also make sure that the `response` `$.post()` should receive only is the necessary HTML and not a whole page (with `<head>`, `<body>`, etc...).

Comment: Without the code the reload doesn't work. 

I do have the form request and post in the code above: <form id="quizForm" action="ajax.php" method="post">

I have tried your version of the script and the main concern of the page getting loaded instead of the div contents being replaced with new content still happens.

I have started setting this up to use on the mobile side of my website and I am unable to get the mobile site to have this problem.  However on desktop this seems to be an issue early, and the `$(document).ready(function () {` didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: could it be an issue with cloudflare? I don't have cloudflare setup for mobile and everything works as it should, but on the cloudflare desktop side it contains this bug.

Comment: Also with the php script the form and javascript/ajax/jquery are reloaded in the new div each time it is reloaded. So it continues to work throughout the entire test.

Comment: **1)** This is not an issue with cloudflare. It should just serves your code to whatever device is requesting it (desktop, mobile, tablet, TV, Raspberry PI, whatever). **2)** Are you really saying that everything work perfectly on mobile? **3)** Clarify how you are loading the page and how you load the `#prntqst` if that is done after the initial page load. **4)** Post the `$.post()` response. **5)** Maybe a live link would help in this case too...

Comment: The desktop version can be found at https://www.cristcdl.com/alabama/al-cdl-practice-tests/general-knowledge-1/

Comment: The mobile can be found at https://m.cristcdl.com/alabama/pt-test.php

Comment: The entire testing system is called in a php document by a line that reads `<?php $quiz->do_quiz_here(); ?>` everything is read out of a xml document by the quiz software and printed in place of that line. So the entire ajax.php file has the needed information to keep the user on the right test, and the do_quiz_here line. This should replace the div with the next question, and the previous question, answer, and explanation.

Comment: As I have said the test works flawlessly on every question after the first. It only messes up on the first question if it is answered and submitted early. If the page completely loads the error doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok... So your script is INSIDE the `#quizForm` and gets reloaded along the div with everything. That was not clear in your question. Now, I tried answering the quiz and i t seems to perfectly work. I'm on desktop with Chrome. What are the steps to reproduce any issue? I saw nothing.

Comment: clear cache, reload the page, and answer as quickly as you can when it loads.

Comment: Nope... I just can't reproduce. Everything seems good. I tried both links.

Comment: Which browser you use?

Comment: https://www.cristcdl.com/i/error-tracking.png    showing a user at the ajax.php right now.

Comment: happens for me in crome, brave, firefox, etc.

Comment: this is what happens with the error. the website is reduced to this.   https://www.cristcdl.com/i/ajax.png

Comment: Edit your question and this time, clearly show everything that is received from the ajax request. Again, it was not clear the script was inside the reloaded div. Making everything I answered irrelevant to your problem. Post that picture from Google analytics. Also post the exact steps to reproduce. -- Your issue is something else than just a jQuery basic syntax... and I don't know. Add the Google Analytics tag. _ suggest you to just delete your question and restart from fresh. ;)